# Select highest ranking category SQL

Tags: sql, search

I have a temp table inside an SQL sproc (used for searching), the columns are ProductID, CategoryID and WeightRank.

From this table I need to get the CategoryID with the highest WeightRank.
I am struggling to figure the syntax, any help would be kindly appreciated.

**Note:** the temp table has many products with the same CategoryID, I need to find the combined WeightRank for each unique CategoryID and return just [highest ranking] CategoryID.
(Hope this makes sense?)

Comment: Which DBMS is this for? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 1 categoryID
from #t
group by categoryID
order by sum(WeightRank) desc
```

or maybe `avg(WeightRank)`?

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL solution allowing for multiple categories that tie for max

```
SELECT *
FROM 
table  t
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT
              SUM( WeightRank) weightRank, category_id 
    FROM 
       table t
    GROUP  by
       category_id 
) sumRank
ON t.category_id  = sumrank.category_id 
INNER JOIN 

SELECT  MAX(weightRank) weightRank
FROM (     
    SELECT
              SUM( WeightRank) weightRank, category_id 
    FROM 
       table t
    GROUP  by
       category_id 
) maxRank

ON sumRank.weightRank= maxRank.weightRank
```